# Translation of "belong together"

Tags: перевод

I found `подходить друг к другу, гармонировать`. However, it sounds a bit like something, that fits together / suits each other.

Is there maybe a way to stress the togetherness/unity/fellowship of two things/people of the same nature?

**Note**: I'm **not** looking for an expression which is used for a romantic relationship between a man and a woman exclusively.

Comment: Can you please clarify what "belong together" means in English?

Comment: @anixx Let's put it like this: Things which are connected by nature or purpose, so that a single one of them is considered incomplete without the others.

Comment: Possibly then, "дополняют друг друга", "supplement each other". Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @anixx That will fit for some cases. It's similar to *they complete one another*, isn't it? I actually find *они (как) одно целое* a good phrase, though I'm uncertain about the connotation this one might hold.

Comment: @embert *одно целое* nice phrase, can be used almost for everything: objects, ideas, people (two and more), ideas with ppl (one and more), etc.

Comment: As in myriads of other questions in this SO, this one provides no context. Context is critical to properly translating. I think that questions w/o clear statement of context should be automatically closed here, as they lead to expanded answers, that are still not necessarily relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to extend Aleks G's answer.
Another quite close example is *они (как) одно целое* or *они как две половинки (одного целого)*. The first one esp. good for things which are not alive.
The following works for things as well:

- *Идеально подогнаны*
- *как тут и было* (when a new part was added)
- *как родное* (e.g. after something was repaired)
- *как влитой*

For both things and people: *два сапога - пара*

For people: *водой не разольешь* or *закадычные друзья*

Joke/informal about two things or even people which are (practically) the same: *из одной бочки наливали*. This originate from a joke:

> A client is asking barman who is swindle but not very smart:
>
> -Why 3-year-old wine has *better* taste than 5-year-old?
>
> -Have no idea, was poured from the same barrel!

Comment: *(как) одно целое* is a quite good one

Answer (score 3):

Especially when talking about people (or couples), but not necessarily, *belong together* is best translated as *созданы друг для друга* (literally *made for each other*):

> They belong together.
>   Они созданы друг для друга.

Another phrase you can often encounter is *суждено быть вместе* (close to English *written in the stars to be together*), however it has a slightly different sub-context: *cуждено быть вместе* implies that they *will* be together while *belong together* implies that they are good together.

Comment: суждено быть вместе - "destined for each other" for me is quite romantic; whereas "belong together" can be said about any two (or more) people with like agendas, personalities, interests, etc. and is platonic as well as potentially romantic.

Comment: @CocoPop I agree, hence this is not the translation I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mean romance, then it is better to say "подходят друг другу", though wider context could give a better understanding

Comment: See OP's note: I'm not looking for an expression which is used for a romantic relationship between a man and a woman exclusively.